# Is Alembic the correct option for me?

Tags: objects, conversion, alembic

I use Blender for Minecraft animations. I make my maps in Minecraft and export them with Mineways in OBJ format. I use quite big maps(around 3 GB). Blender can't open big files or takes a long time. Should I convert OBJ to Alembic (ABC) to improve this and how?

Comment: Hope you don't mind me editing your question. I tried to improve it since you said your English was not very good. If I changed the meaning you intended please let me know or edit it back to the way you prefer it.

Comment: Thanks for your improve. You don't changed the meaning. :)